# How to set a selected option of a dropdown list control using angular JS

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-ngmodel, selected

I am using Angular JS and I need to set a selected option of a dropdown list control using angular JS. Forgive me if this is ridiculous but I am new with Angular JS

Here is the dropdown list control of my HTML:

```html
 <select ng-required="item.id==8 && item.quantity > 0" name="posterVariants"
   ng-show="item.id==8" ng-model="item.selectedVariant" 
   ng-change="calculateServicesSubTotal(item)"
   ng-options="v.name for v in variants | filter:{type:2}">
  </select>
```

After it gets populated I get

```
 <select ng-options="v.name for v in variants | filter:{type:2}" ng-change="calculateServicesSubTotal(item)"
ng-model="item.selectedVariant" ng-show="item.id==8" name="posterVariants"
ng-required="item.id==8 &amp;&amp; item.quantity &gt; 0" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required">
    <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="0">set of 6 traits</option>
    <option value="1">5 complete sets</option>
</select>
```

How can I set the control for `value="0"` to be selected?

Comment: `<option value="0" ng-selected="true">set of 6 traits</option>`

Answer (score 198, accepted):

I hope I understand your question, but the `ng-model` directive creates a two-way binding between the selected item in the control and the value of `item.selectedVariant`. This means that changing `item.selectedVariant` in JavaScript, or changing the value in the control, updates the other. If `item.selectedVariant` has a value of `0`, that item should get selected.

If `variants` is an array of objects, `item.selectedVariant` must be set to one of those objects. I do not know which information you have in your scope, but here's an example:

JS:

```
$scope.options = [{ name: "a", id: 1 }, { name: "b", id: 2 }];
$scope.selectedOption = $scope.options[1];
```

HTML:

```
<select data-ng-options="o.name for o in options" data-ng-model="selectedOption"></select>
```

This would leave the "b" item to be selected.

Comment: I have a controler file named order.js, thus the html name the same order.html where the control is. Should I set the selectedVariant there or directly on the control?

Comment: Usually you would set these things in the controller, on the `$scope` variable. So assuming you're in a single scope, in your controller you could say `$scope.item.selectedVariant = 0`, to set the default selected value. You could also set the variable directly on the control, in HTML, using the [ng-init](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit) directive, but that gets rather messy in my opinion!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what `variants` is on your scope? You would have to set `item.selectedVariant` exactly to an item of `variants`.

Comment: $scope.item.selectedVariant = 0; this will break up the page if I put it in the controler file

Comment: can you provide the syntax using ng-init please?

Comment: I updated my answer with a sample where the data is an array of objects, which I believe your situation is. Hope that helps.

Comment: Please see this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2COBn7Pl5J9LOyNI6tba?p=preview) for a working example, and try to retrace the steps!

Comment: you may check out my code please http://pastebin.com/HdktBk4T and http://pastebin.com/yEnqEDMc

Comment: This is what i have been looking for almost two days of combing Stackoverflow. Thank you @stevuu

Comment: Thanks. I have somewhat an extension of this question. If user selects b what should I do to get 2 into my js?

Comment: @yalkris Use the "as" operator as described in [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)! It allows you to change what is the value for a given element, for example `o.id as o.name for o in options` (or `o.name as o.id for o in options`, depending on what you meant).

Comment: How to do the same if the drop down is a multi select one?

Comment: what to do if my data-ng-model="formA.selectedOption"?

Answer (score 36):

I don't know if this will help anyone or not but as I was facing the same issue I thought of sharing how I got the solution.

You can use **track by** attribute in your `ng-options`.

Assume that you have:

```
variants:[{'id':0, name:'set of 6 traits'}, {'id':1, name:'5 complete sets'}]
```

You can mention your `ng-options` as:

```
ng-options="v.name for v in variants track by v.id"
```

Hope this helps someone in future.

Comment: This is what I was missing! I was setting the scope field that was bound to `ngModel` properly, but it didn't work until I added the `track by`! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

If you assign value 0 to `item.selectedVariant` it should be selected automatically.
Check out sample on http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select which selects red color by default by simply assigning `$scope.color='red'`.

Comment: where do I set the item.selectedVariant? if I define $scope.item.selectedVariant = 0; in the controler of the file, angular breaks up

Comment: could you also paste matching html?

Comment: I think each item in orderGrid needs to have selectedVariant set to 0

Comment: can you provide a sample code? I am not familiar with angular sorry

Answer (score 7):

i see here already wrote good answers, but sometime to write the same in other form can be helpful

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="referral.organization" ng-options="c for c in organizations"></select>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.organizations = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
    $scope.referral = {
      organization: $scope.organizations[2]
    };
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What if I had a drop down that was multi select . Simply setting the ids in the model is not working

Answer (score 2):

#### Simple way

If you have a Users as response or a Array/JSON you defined, First You need to set the selected value in controller, then you put the same model name in html. This example i wrote to explain in easiest way.
**Simple example**
Inside Controller:

```
$scope.Users = ["Suresh","Mahesh","Ramesh"]; 
$scope.selectedUser = $scope.Users[0];
```

Your HTML

```
<select data-ng-options="usr for usr in Users" data-ng-model="selectedUser">
</select>
```

**complex example**
Inside Controller:

```
$scope.JSON = {
       "ResponseObject":
           [{
               "Name": "Suresh",
               "userID": 1
           },
           {
               "Name": "Mahesh",
               "userID": 2
           }]
   };
   $scope.selectedUser = $scope.JSON.ResponseObject[0];
```

Your HTML

```
<select data-ng-options="usr.Name for usr in JSON.ResponseObject" data-ng-model="selectedUser"></select>
<h3>You selected: {{selectedUser.Name}}</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be usefull. Bindings dose not always work.

```
<select id="product" class="form-control" name="product" required
        ng-model="issue.productId"
        ng-change="getProductVersions()"
        ng-options="p.id as p.shortName for p in products">
</select>
```

For example. You fill options list source model from rest-service. Selected value was known befor filling list and was set. After executing rest-request with $http list option be done. But selected option is not set. By unknown reasons AngularJS in shadow $digest executing not bind selected as it shuold be. I gotta use JQuery to set selected. It`s important! Angular in shadow add prefix to value of attr "value" for generated by ng-repeat optinos. For int it is "number:".

```
$scope.issue.productId = productId;
function activate() {
   $http.get('/product/list')
     .then(function (response) {
       $scope.products = response.data;

       if (productId) {
           console.log("" + $("#product option").length);//for clarity                       
           $timeout(function () {
               console.log("" + $("#product option").length);//for clarity
               $('#product').val('number:'+productId);
               //$scope.issue.productId = productId;//not work at all
           }, 200);
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

JS file

```
this.options = { 
        languages: [{language: 'English', lg:'en'}, {language:'German', lg:'de'}]
};
console.log(signinDetails.language);
```

HTML file

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label>Preferred language</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="right" ng-model="signinDetails.language" ng-init="signinDetails.language = options.languages[0]" ng-options="l as l.language for l in options.languages"><option></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: There is already a good solution, that works and has been accepted by OP that it solves his issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code what I used for the set selected value

```js
countryList: any = [{ "value": "AF", "group": "A", "text": "Afghanistan"}, { "value": "AL", "group": "A", "text": "Albania"}, { "value": "DZ", "group": "A", "text": "Algeria"}, { "value": "AD", "group": "A", "text": "Andorra"}, { "value": "AO", "group": "A", "text": "Angola"}, { "value": "AR", "group": "A", "text": "Argentina"}, { "value": "AM", "group": "A", "text": "Armenia"}, { "value": "AW", "group": "A", "text": "Aruba"}, { "value": "AU", "group": "A", "text": "Australia"}, { "value": "AT", "group": "A", "text": "Austria"}, { "value": "AZ", "group": "A", "text": "Azerbaijan"}];
 
 
 for (var j = 0; j < countryList.length; j++) {
      //debugger
      if (countryList[j].text == "Australia") {
          console.log(countryList[j].text); 
          countryList[j].isSelected = 'selected';
      }
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<label>Country</label>
<select class="custom-select col-12" id="Country" name="Country"   >
<option value="0" selected>Choose...</option>
<option *ngFor="let country of countryList" value="{{country.text}}" selected="{{country.isSelected}}"   > {{country.text}}</option>
</select>
```

try this on an angular framework

Answer (score 0):

**JS:**

```js
$scope.options = [
  {
    name: "a", 
    id: 1 
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    id: 2 
  }
];
$scope.selectedOption = $scope.options[1];
```