# how to populate a drop down menu with data coming to controller using http get in angular js

Tags: json, angularjs

This is the JSON file ..
Using angular js controller and view how can I parse this json and display the drop1 and drop2 values of respective technology in drop down menu.getting the JSON data using http get.
Thanks in advance

```
 {
        "technology": [
            {
                "id": "AKC",
                "detail": {
                    "drop1": [
                        {
                            "id": "AKC-lst-1231"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "AKC-lst-1232"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "AKC-lst-1233"
                        }
                    ],
                    "drop2": [
                        {
                            "id": "T_AKC_live"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "T_AKC_Capt"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "T_AKC_live1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "MET",
                "detail": {
                    "drop1": [
                        {
                            "id": "MET-2st"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "MET-34"
                        }
                    ],
                    "drop2": [
                        {
                            "id": "sd-232"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "sd-121"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: c'mon what did you even try?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="postExample">
     <head>
          <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.22" data-semver="1.2.22" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js"></script>
          <script src="usersController.js"></script>
          <script src="userRepoService.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="UsersController">
        <h1>Post Angular Example</h1>
        <select id="UserSelector" style="width: 100%;">
            <option ng-repeat="user in users" value="{{user.id}}">{{user.login}}   </option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

userRepoService.js

```
(function(){

var userRepoService = function($http){

  var getUsers = function(username){
        return $http.get("https://api.github.com/users")
                    .then(function(response){
                       return response.data; 
                    });
  };

  return {
      get: getUsers
  };

};

var module = angular.module("postExample");
module.factory("userRepoService", userRepoService);

}());
```

Controller:

```
(function(){

   var app = angular.module("postExample",[]);

   var UsersController = function($scope, userRepoService){

   var onFetchError = function(message){
      $scope.error = "Error Fetching Users. Message:" +message;
 };

   var onFetchCompleted = function(data){
      $scope.users =data;
   };

   var getUsers = function(){
       userRepoService.get().then(onFetchCompleted,onFetchError);
   };

   getUsers();     

};

app.controller("UsersController", UsersController);

}());
```

Comment: Please visit this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968760/how-to-set-a-selected-option-of-a-dropdown-list-control-using-angular-js) also

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call `$http` service, and get that response inside success data parameter.

**CODE**

```
$http.get("test.json").
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  //get data and play with it
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  alert("Error fetching data");
  // log error
});
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.