# How to set default option in Angular select element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set the default option in a select element in an Angular app. Below is what I've tried, but my select box is empty:

```
<select ng-init="selectedMax = game.player.max_points"
        ng-options="option for option in game.maxOptions"
        ng-model="selectedMax"
        ng-change="changeMax()"></select>
```

Basically I want my default option to be `game.player.max_points` which is a value set by my controller on initiation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968760/how-to-set-a-selected-option-of-a-dropdown-list-control-using-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

Select one of the available options:

```
<select ng-init="selectedMax = game.maxOptions[0]" ng-options="option for option in game.maxOptions" ng-model="selectedMax" ng-change="changeMax()"></select>
```

or try setting it in your controller: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqxmvG

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to tell to the ng-options directive what field to use from the options array. Something like this:

```
<select ng-init="selectedMax = game.player.max_points" 
        ng-options="option.fieldName for option in game.maxOptions"
        ng-model="selectedMax" 
        ng-change="changeMax()">
</select>
```