# Set selected item selected option

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my ionic project I have a `<select>` like so:

```
<select ng-model="user.bloodType" ng-options="x as x.description for x in formData.bloodTypes"></select>
```

So to clarify, `user.bloodType` is an object that looks like this:

```
{
  'id' : 1,
  'description' : 'O+'
}
```

`formData.bloodTypes` contains an array of the above depicted `bloodType` object. So here comes the problem - I know that `user.bloodType` is definitely one of the objects that is in `formData.bloodTypes`. How can I set the `<select>` to be pre-selected on whatever `user.bloodType` is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a selected option of a dropdown list control using angular JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968760/how-to-set-a-selected-option-of-a-dropdown-list-control-using-angular-js)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not using reference equality to set ngModel to one of the options, you can rely on equality based on id by using a `track by` expression (the id should be unique per option):

```
ng-options="x as x.description for x in formData.bloodTypes track by x.id"
```

Then your ngModel user.bloodType can be initialized to a model whose reference does not necessarily match.

For example:

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="x 
          as x.description for x in bloodTypes track by x.id>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.bloodTypes = [
       {'id' : 1, 'description' : 'O+'},         
       {'id' : 2, 'description' : 'A'},
       {'id' : 3, 'description' : 'B'},
     ];

     // set initial selected option to blood type B
     $scope.selectedOption =  {'id' : 3, 'description' : 'B'};
});
```

Or if you want to preserve reference equality, you don't need track by:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.bloodTypes = [
       {'id' : 1, 'description' : 'O+'},         
       {'id' : 2, 'description' : 'A'},
       {'id' : 3, 'description' : 'B'},
     ];

     // set initial selected option to blood type B
     $scope.selectedOption = $scope.bloodTypes[2];    
});
```

Comment: Could the above potentially be simplified then by doing this: <select ng-model="user.bloodType" ng-options="x as x.description for x in formData.bloodTypes"  ng-selected="user.bloodType"></select> // Just added ng-selected="user.bloodType"

Comment: No. It doesn't make much sense to mix the two. Use one or the other. ngModel is more useful - means less work in syncing the model