# angularjs -Setting the selected value in a select dropdown when editing an item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I set the selected value of a dropdown when I edit an item ?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select ng-model="quiz.category" ng-options="category as category.name for category in categories" required>
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And when I click on edit

```
$scope.editQuiz = function(quiz)
    {   
        $scope.quiz = {};
        $scope.quiz.name = quiz.name // this works fine
        $scope.quiz.category = quiz.category[0]; // ?????
        console.log($scope.quiz.category);
        //$scope.quiz = quiz;  

    }
```

Method to get categories:

```
$scope.getCategories = function() {
    $http.get('http://localhost/myappi/API/index.php/Api/categories').
        success(function(data) {

            $scope.categories = data;   
        })
        .error(function(err) {
        console.log('error',err);
    })
    };
```

Comment: just `quiz.category`

Comment: quiz.category will give me an Array[1] , quiz.category[0] will give me the object. forgot to mention.

Comment: do you have multiple select?

Comment: I have one select that is populated by a list called categories(that I get from a server).

Comment: can you give the structure of the categories collection?

Comment: quiz.category holds always one item? or you may have multiple categories?

Comment: Only one category, but I think I explaned it wrong. I managed to add a quiz and attach a category to it. Now I'm trying basically to edit a quiz and change it's category. I will add a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if you really want to keep quiz.category as an array.
At first when you `get` the quiz assign `quiz.category` to an new object.
e.g:

```
$scope.tmp = { category: quiz.category[0] };
```

We have to do that since `quiz.category` is an array but the value of the `ng-options` is an object.

now we can bind that var to the options like this:

```
<select ng-model="tmp.category" ng-options="category as category.name for category in categories" required>
        <option></option>
</select>
```

and finally in your function you replace the old value with the new:

```
$scope.quiz.category[0] = tmp.category;
```

Hope it makes sense

Comment: Thanks for the help changed it to a model and managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the select's ngModel is definitely the way to go. You can check out this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968760/how-to-set-a-selected-option-of-a-dropdown-list-control-using-angular-js), since I believe it deals with the same problem.

`$scope.options = [{ name: "a", id: 1 }, { name: "b", id: 2 }];
 $scope.selectedOption = $scope.options[1];`

`<select data-ng-options="o.name for o in options" data-ng-model="selectedOption"></select>`

Can you send us your data structure sample?

Answer (score 0):

Use "track by" inside the ng-options

```
category as category.name for category in categories track by category.id
```

working [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVvqZB?editors=101)