# How to get selected value from select box in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Hello Everyone**

I am trying to get option value from select box on button click but it shows undefined in console .Options value are coming from server

Here is my html code

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-form" for="cityid">Selct City</label>
        <select type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" id="acity" >
            <option value="">--Select City--</option>
            <option ng-repeat="city in cityinfo" ng-value="{{city.id}}"  ng-selected="{{city.id ==cityid}}">{{city.cityname}}</option>
</select>

<button class="btn btn-info prevnext pull-right" ng-click="nextpage()">Next <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
```

Controller.js file code

```
  $scope.nextpage = function(pageno) {
   console.log($scope.cityinfo);
   }
```

[image: Select box image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a selected option of a dropdown list control using angular JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968760/how-to-set-a-selected-option-of-a-dropdown-list-control-using-angular-js)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`.

Like this:

**Updated**

```
<select type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" id="acity" ng-options="city.id as city.cityname for city in cityinfo track by city.id" ng-model="selectedCity">
    <option value="">--Select City--</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-info prevnext pull-right" ng-click="nextpage(selectedCity)">Next <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.nextpage = function(selectedCity){
    console.log(selectedCity);
}
```

Comment: it is not working i want to any selected value of option

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the sample code.**

**Html code**

```
 <select type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" id="acity" ng-options="city.id as city.cityname for city in cityinfo track by city.id" ng-model="currentCity">
    <option value="">--Select Cities--</option>
</select>
 <button class="btn btn-info prevnext pull-right" ng- 
  click="nextpage(currentCity)">Next <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> 
  </button>
```

**JS function**

```
$scope.nextpage = function(currentCity){
    console.log(currentCity);
}
```