# Get select option value when click on button in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

I have trouble to get the selected option value.

**View**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="mySel">
    <option ng-repeat="option in Array" value="@{{ option.id }}">@{{ option.name }}</option>
</select>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getData(mySel);">Select</button>
```

**Controller**

```
scope.getData = function(selectedValue) {
    alert(selectedValue);
}
```

This returns `undefined`.

Comment: post your whole HTML code

Comment: Duplicity with [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400048/how-to-get-selected-value-from-select-box-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

No need to pass `selectedValue` from html use `ng-model` instead

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getData();">Select</button>

   $scope.getData = function() {
    console.log($scope.mySel);
   }
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utpkyv07/)