# Couldn't add a value to a ng-model in combobox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, combobox

I am trying to add a value to combobox with dynamic data. The problem is the value doesn't show in my combobox as selected.

Here's my `html`

```
<label>Veuillez choisir l'outil de référence  :</label>
<select class="form-control"  
        ng-model="refouti" 
        ng-change="getversion()">
    <option value="" selected>
        Tous
    </option>
    <option ng-repeat="o in outills" 
            value={{o.id}}>
        {{o.nomref}}
    </option>
</select>
```

In my controller when I want to add value to `refouti` like this:

```
 $scope.refouti="OPCOM";
```

i get something like this

[image]

Thanks to any support.

Comment: you want to add value as a default value?

Comment: no it's not a default value i didn't want to paste all the code because it will look more complicate `$scope.refouti=dynamic value wich change on each condition ` ps if i wanted to add a default value i would add an option with that value

Comment: I suggest you use ng-options instead of ng-repeat in select.

Comment: I agree with @SSH, use `ng-options`

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-options on the select.

Here's what's happening:

Your ng-repeat works, it prints out multiple `<option>` tags. **BUT** without using ng-options, angular doesn't really know he's playing with a select. Therefor, changing the value of the `ng-model` directly changes the 'value' of the select box, which it empties. In your case, you would need to push a new array object to `$scope.outills` (or overwrite), and not `$scope.refouti`

Comment: okey i agree with you in this but i tried using ng-option it still the same issue i can't display something when i make this `$scope.refouti=anyvalue` ps in ng option i have the same ng-model i didn't change it like this `ng-model="selected"` , the issue here is how can i make a that value `anyvalue` look as selected in my combobox

Comment: Maybe this will answer your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968760/how-to-set-a-selected-option-of-a-dropdown-list-control-using-angular-js