# set selected value of drop down list in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

HTML code

```
<div>
            <label for="name">School Name</label>
            <select ng-model="SelectedSchoolIDEdit"
                    ng-options="option.Name for option in SchoolAvailableOptions track by option.ID"></select>
        </div>
```

Angular code

```
 SchoolGradesService.GetAllSchools().then(function (d) {
    $scope.SchoolAvailableOptions = d.data;// Success
    $scope.SelectedSchoolIDEdit = $scope.SchoolAvailableOptions[0].ID;
}, function () {
    alert('Error Occured !!!'); // Failed
});
```

The situation like that i get data successfully and i can fill the drop down list but 
The problem is that I cant set the default value on it
And I search a lot and i see the same what I do ,SO I cannot catch the problem
Note: I am new with Angular

Comment: did you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968760/how-to-set-a-selected-option-of-a-dropdown-list-control-using-angular-js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution for my problem. I did a data mockup of your data. I was able to select the option, when the scope variable `$scope.SelectedSchoolIDEdit` will need to have the syntax to be.

```
$scope.SelectedSchoolIDEdit = {ID: 1};
```

So to solve your problem, the code that uses the service should be like this.

```
SchoolGradesService.GetAllSchools().then(function (d) {
    $scope.SchoolAvailableOptions = d.data;// Success
    $scope.SelectedSchoolIDEdit = {ID: $scope.SchoolAvailableOptions[0].ID};
}, function () {
    alert('Error Occured !!!'); // Failed
});
```

Here is a working example of how the data should be for the options to be selected.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Can you please check if this change fixes your issue?

Comment: It would be better to assign the first element of `SchoolAvailableOptions` array to `SelectedSchoolIDEdit`, instead of creating a hard coded element.

Comment: @PrerakSola I am stating the problem alone.  Plus in your answer too there is a `track by option.ID` that is not even needed, if we use your method I think!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$scope.SelectedSchoolIDEdit = $scope.SchoolAvailableOptions[0].ID;`
by `$scope.SelectedSchoolIDEdit = $scope.SchoolAvailableOptions[0];`

Check the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prerak6962/2ksjf83p/2/)

Comment: @Radwa See the updated answer. I have added an example.

Answer (score 0):

## try this

```
<select ng-init="SelectedSchoolIDEdit=SchoolAvailableOptions[0].ID" ng-model="SelectedSchoolIDEdit"
                ng-options="option.ID as option.Name for option in SchoolAvailableOptions track by option.ID"></select>
```